# Dalvik virtual machine instruction set and architecture

Tags: android, dalvik, opcode, vm-implementation

How does the Dalvik virtual machine compare to a real hardware platform such as X86 or ARM?

1. How many registers does Dalvik have?

   - 8 like the X86
   - 16 like most common CPUs
   - Infinity with register window like Parrot VM
2. What type of instruction is Dalvik more like?

   - RISC
   - CISC
3. How many Operands does Dalvik support?

   - Most have three though the X86 has only two?
4. What type is used in Dalvik?

   - Register-Register
   - Register-Memory
   - Register-Register/ Register-Memory
5. What type of Instruction encoding is used in Dalvik?

   - Variable
   - Fixed
6. How long are the instructions for Dalvik?

   - 8 bits
   - 16 bits
   - 32 bits
   - something else maybe?
7. How does the Dalvik VM compare as far as performance in comparison to real bare hardware?
8. Finally what Endianness is Dalvik?

   - Big
   - Little
   - Bi

Comment: This is the biggest quiestion I have seen..

Comment: @amalBit it's about the instruction set and I want to know how the Dalvik VM is in comparison to a real machine

Comment: 1. Dalvik has a set of ranges for its registers 16, 256, 16,535.
2. Dalvik is closer to RISC than CISC because it is more of a load-store architecture, however, it does have some complex operations like string and object handling that might be found on a CISC like architecture.
3. Dalvik has many instructions each with a fixed number of operands; they range from 0 to 3 operands.
4. Register-Register because all operands must be in a register to be operated on

Comment: 5. Dalvik uses a variable length instruction set.
6. Each of dalviks instructions are a variable length but they are read in fixed 16 bit words.
7. Dalvik is several magnitudes slower than bare hardware, this is due to the fact that Dalvik is an abstraction and not bare hardware.
8. Dalvik is a little endian architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many registers does Dalvik have?

[In dalvik's bytecode, registers are always 32 bits, and can hold any type of value. 2 registers are used to hold 64 bit types (Long and Double).](https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/Registers)

> What type of instruction is Dalvik more like?

[This link might help.](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html)

[More about dalvik execution.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jfoster/papers/cs-tr-5022.pdf)